# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'. SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Please help me in understanding the below

Why is

```
(select top 1 * from dbo.module order by [order])
```

throwing an error?

When

```
select top 1 * from dbo.module
```

and

```
select top 1 * from dbo.module order by [order]
```

are not?

Comment: @Yeou, I am more inclined to understand whats wrong with the parenthesis.

Comment: You need to keep order by outside parenthesis (select top 1 * from dbo.module) order by [order]

Comment: order by should always be last statement for the query you write. thats why it should be outside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because SQL server execute statements, and the statements have the exact syntax specified for them.

The SELECT statement must start with SELECT keyword.
If the statement starts with bracket, it is subquery, and you cannot use 'Order by' in it.

Comment: >>>If the statement starts with bracket, it is subquery, and you cannot use 'Order by' in it.<<< In OP's case "subquery" has **top 1**, so if it is subquery, order by is permitted in it. So it's not a question of "being subquery". For example, this one does not produce any error even if it has subquery with ORDER BY: `select * from (select top 1 * from dbo.module order by [order])t`

Comment: Nice explanation, you should make it to answer!

Answer (score 1):

Having brackets around the whole statement is not an ok syntax/statment. This works:

```
 (SELECT top 1 * FROM dbo.module) ORDER BY [order]
```